# Drawing Multiple Lines with Non-Overlapping Y Values

Tags: javascript, json, google-visualization

Okay, so I should start off by saying we sort of found a way around this by generating null values for every line except the one being drawn. The idea is that we're drawing power levels (y) and frequency (x), but these values shouldn't overlap except in a very rare case. C# and ASP.NET charts would work well for this, but we're trying to move away from them since Google's Visualization API is cleaner, easier to work with and maintain, and faster.

I tried formatting the JSON so that there were multiple rows and columns so it looked like:

```
{
  cols: [{id: 'A', label: 'NEW A', type: 'string'},
         {id: 'B', label: 'B-label', type: 'number'},
         {id: 'C', label: 'C-label', type: 'date'}
        ],
  rows: [{c:[{v: 'a'}, {v: 1.0, f: 'One'}, {v: new Date(2008, 1, 28, 0, 31, 26), f: '2/28/08 12:31 AM'}]},
         {c:[{v: 'b'}, {v: 2.0, f: 'Two'}, {v: new Date(2008, 2, 30, 0, 31, 26), f: '3/30/08 12:31 AM'}]},
         {c:[{v: 'c'}, {v: 3.0, f: 'Three'}, {v: new Date(2008, 3, 30, 0, 31, 26), f: '4/30/08 12:31 AM'}]}
        ],
  cols: [{id: 'A', label: 'NEW A', type: 'string'},
         {id: 'B', label: 'B-label', type: 'number'},
         {id: 'C', label: 'C-label', type: 'date'}
        ],
  rows: [{c:[{v: 'a'}, {v: 1.0, f: 'One'}, {v: new Date(2008, 1, 28, 0, 31, 26), f: '2/28/08 12:31 AM'}]},
         {c:[{v: 'b'}, {v: 2.0, f: 'Two'}, {v: new Date(2008, 2, 30, 0, 31, 26), f: '3/30/08 12:31 AM'}]},
         {c:[{v: 'c'}, {v: 3.0, f: 'Three'}, {v: new Date(2008, 3, 30, 0, 31, 26), f: '4/30/08 12:31 AM'}]}
        ],
}
```

Unfortunately, I determined that this would only draw the final line displayed in the JSON, which if you think about the way CSS chooses things kind of makes sense for JavaScript, too.

I also tried multiple row sets for a single column set and it sort of worked, but it connected the lines. As I said, there's a case where this is undesirable as there are occasionally lines which share the same x values and cause the line to reach its terminal point and draw a connecting line back to the beginning of the next point.

Still, it seems a bit ridiculous that x values would have to overlap. Has anyone found a way to draw multiple lines, treat things as separate series, or add points by x and y value alone with a corresponding legend item? I haven't found anything like this in their API or SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each line in your chart needs to come from a separate data series, so if you want two lines, you need to have two data series.  The x-axis points need not be the same for both, you just insert null values for the series that don't have a value at a particular x-axis point.  Here's an example DataTable that you could use to draw two lines in a chart:

```
{
    "cols":[
        {"id":"","label":"X","type":"number"},
        {"id":"","label":"Y1","type":"number"},
        {"id":"","label":"Y2","type":"number"}
    ],
    "rows":[
        {"c":[{"v":1},{"v":2},{"v":8}]},
        {"c":[{"v":2},{"v":null},{"v":6}]},
        {"c":[{"v":3},{"v":5},{"v":6}]},
        {"c":[{"v":4},{"v":0},{"v":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":5},{"v":9},{"v":7}]},
        {"c":[{"v":6},{"v":7},{"v":2}]}
    ]
}
```

see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/M7STT/

[Edit - alternative organization]

You can also organize the data like this, if its easier to do for you:

```
{
    "cols":[
        {"id":"","label":"X","type":"number"},
        {"id":"","label":"Y1","type":"number"},
        {"id":"","label":"Y2","type":"number"}
    ],
    "rows":[
        // Y1 data:
        {"c":[{"v":1},{"v":2},{"v":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":3},{"v":5},{"v":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":4},{"v":0},{"v":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":5},{"v":9},{"v":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":6},{"v":7},{"v":null}]},
        // Y2 data:
        {"c":[{"v":1},{"v":null},{"v":8}]},
        {"c":[{"v":2},{"v":null},{"v":6}]},
        {"c":[{"v":3},{"v":null},{"v":6}]},
        {"c":[{"v":5},{"v":null},{"v":7}]},
        {"c":[{"v":6},{"v":null},{"v":2}]}
    ]
}
```

Updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/M7STT/3/

Comment: Right, but the point is to have the blue line with data values where the red line doesn't and vice versa. I have charts like that one working. What I'm looking for is a way to make it so the x values don't necessarily have to overlap. In that chart there's a single x for n y values (where n is 2 in your example). So, for example, say it's two baseball players' careers of time vs. home runs and one player began in 1990 and the other in 1992. One is active until 2002 and the other until today.

Comment: If you look at the data, you will see that not all points line up.  Y1 does not exist at x = 2 and Y2 does not exist at x = 4.  Any time a value doesn't exist at a given x-axis point, you just put `null` as the value.

Comment: Oh, okay. You've got the same solution we're probably going to use (mentioned above), which is to generate null data points. My question was more if there was an easier way to do this supported by the API?

Comment: Define "easier".  This is pretty easy to set up in most cases.  You could also enter the data for an entire data set in one set of rows (leaving the other column null), and then repeat for the second data set (leaving the first column null) if that's "easier".  I'll update my post with an example.

Comment: Yeah, I had that idea, as well. My hope was that I was missing something in the API that let me draw the chart line-by-line or point-by-point with an associated line. If I can't do that, this is a fair solution and since no one else has come up with an answer, I'm inclined to guess it's a corner case, so you win the answer points. Thanks for the input!